# I am unable to knit/compile .R files in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

This is what I type in the source pane

```
x <- c(1,3,2,5)
x
x = c(1,6,2)
x
y = c(1,4,3)
length(x)
length(y)
x+y
ls()
rm(x,y)
ls()
rm(list=ls())
?matrix
x=matrix(data=c(1,2,3,4), nrow=2, ncol=2)
x
x=matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2)
matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2,byrow=TRUE)
sqrt(x)
x^2
x=rnorm(50)
y=x+rnorm(50,mean=50,sd=.1)
cor(x,y)
set.seed(1303)
rnorm(50)
set.seed(3)
y=rnorm(100)
mean(y)
var(y)
sqrt(var(y))
sd(y)
```

But when I do any of the three actions mentioned below, the .R file changes

1. Trying to save the .R file
2. Trying to knit the file using File Menu> Knit Document
3. Trying to compile the document using File Menu> Compile Report

On any of these actions, the .R file changes to

```
x <- c(1,3,2,5) x x = c(1,6,2) x y = c(1,4,3) length(x) length(y) x+y ls() rm(x,y) ls() rm(list=ls()) ?matrix x=matrix(data=c(1,2,3,4), nrow=2, ncol=2) x x=matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2) matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2,byrow=TRUE) sqrt(x) x^2 x=rnorm(50) y=x+rnorm(50,mean=50,sd=.1) cor(x,y) set.seed(1303) rnorm(50) set.seed(3) y=rnorm(100) mean(y) var(y) sqrt(var(y)) sd(y)
```

As you can see, the code loses all the formatting. Apart from that, it also get irrelevant characters like \.

My system details are as follows:
RStudio Edition : 
RStudio Version : 1.4.779
OS Version      : Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)
R Version       : 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)

Because of this problem, I have to save all my code as text file in Notepad or any other text editor, so that I can use the same code in my next session. How can I correct this issue in RStudio?

Comment: By "in the console", do you mean that you try to save what is written in the console as a R script? If you want to save your code, you can use RStudio, `File -> New File -> R script `

Comment: Also I was not able to reproduce your error, copy/paste your code in and R script, save and reopen do not change the structure

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to do. The notion of "knitting a document" only applies to r-markdown files (.Rmd). .R files are just scripts and as such cannot be knitted.

Comment: @Phil .R files can also be knitted. Earlier, when I didn't know R Markdown concept, I have knitted .R files as well. But only since Rstudio 1.4.xxx versions, I am unable to do such thing. I suspect it is related to encoding that Rstudio forces, but I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @Paul can you share which Rstudio version you are using? I am on Rstudio 1.4.781, which is a daily build. If you have a stable version of Rstudio (which would have version number 1.3.xxx or less), then I can conclude that the problem is related to my version only.

Comment: @Eva my RStudio version is 1.2.1335. I will update it.

Comment: @Eva now updated to Version 1.3.1073. Saving your example as .R file and reopening it do not change the format.

Comment: @Paul Thanks a lot. I also changed the versions of Rstudio. First tried it on 1.4.787, which is also daily build. Then recreated the same example in stable version, 1.3.1073. But didn't face this issue. So, I guess it was specific to Rstudio 1.4.779 only.

Comment: I found similar issue raised by someone on Rstudio community forum and github, with code taken from same ISLR book. So, I guess from there the Rstudio team has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As @Paul and @Phil commented, the issue doesn't exist in RStudio 1.2.xxxx or 1.3.xxxx versions. This issue was specific to RStudio daily build version 1.4.779. After the issue was raised in github and RStudio Community Forum, the issue seems to be fixed in the newer versions of RStudio daily builds.